# Find the value of the the term

Tags: recurrence-relations

The sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ satisfies $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, and $$a_{n+2}=\frac2{a_{n+1}}+a_n\;;$$ find the value of

$$\frac{a_{2012}2^{2009}}{2011}$$

Comment: Please check to be sure that I correctly interpreted the mathematical expressions.

Comment: ya its correct.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you have tried, or where this question came from so that we can answer appropriately.

Comment: it is a problem of a test.!!!

Comment: i have already spent 2 hours on this

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$a_{n+2}=\frac2{a_{n+1}}+a_n\iff a_{n+2}a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}a_n+2$$

$$\implies a_{n+2}a_{n+1}=2n+a_2a_1=2n+2\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$\text{Replacing }n\text{ with } n-1,\implies a_{n+1}a_n=2n$$

$$\implies a_{n+2}a_{n+1}\cdot2n=a_{n+1}a_n(2n+2)$$

$$\implies a_{n+2} =a_n\frac{(n+1)}n$$

$$n=2m-2\implies a_{2m} =a_{2m-2}\frac{(2m-1)}{2m-2}$$

$$ a_{2m} =\frac{(2m-1)(2m-3)\cdots3}{(2m-2)(2m-4)\cdots4}a_2$$

$$\text{Now,} \frac{(2m-1)(2m-3)\cdots3}{(2m-2)(2m-4)\cdots4}=2\frac{(2m-1)(2m-2)\cdots4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{2^{m-1}\cdot (m-1)! ((2m-2)\cdot4\cdot2)}=\frac{(2m-1)!}{2^{2m-2} \{(m-1)!\}^2}$$ and $a_2=2$

Comment: Can anybody please verify this?

Comment: how did u write a(n+1)a(n) =2n

Comment: @mathslover, Replacing $n$ with $n−1$

Comment: is it not that for any value of n greater than 2, $a_{n} $=2  ? can we not use that to say $a_{2012} = 2 $. why its wrong ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, what should it be?

Comment: the step ...a(n+2)a(n+1) =2n+a2a1.!!@labbhattacharjee ..cant understand this

Comment: @mathslover, if $b_n=b_{n-1}+2, b_n=2(n-r)+b_r,$  for $0\le r\le n-1$  $r=n-1\implies b_n=2(n-1)+b_1$

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam a4=a3/2 +a2;a4=1+2=3

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, sorry for the mistake. Could you please verify once?

Comment: It’s still not right, as you check by computing a few values. My last comment left out a factor; the correct expression is $$\frac{(2m-1)!}{2^{m-2}(m-1)!2^{m-1}(m-1)!}= \frac{(2m-1)!}{2^{2m-3}(m-1)!^2}=\frac{m}{2^{2m-2}}\binom{2m}m\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks for your support

Comment: You’re welcome, but you’re still off by a factor of $2$: you want $2^{2m-3}(m-1)!^2$ in the denominator. (I double-checked against the computed values of $a_6$ and $a_8$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I think that before multiplying by $a_2$, lab's answer is correct. At least it matches my verification.

Comment: @robjohn: You’re right: I didn’t notice that he’d dropped the $a_2$ in the final expression.

Answer (score 2):

As lab bhattacharjee shows, $a_{n+2}a_{n+1}=2n+2$, and thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}
&=\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{n}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{2n}}{a_2}
&=\frac{2n-1}{2n-2}\frac{2n-3}{2n-4}\cdots\frac32\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\frac1{4^{n-1}}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!}}\\
&=\frac{n}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align}
$$
and since $a_2=2$,
$$
a_{2n}=\frac{n}{4^{n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}
$$
I believe this verifies lab's hint (in red).